# Remove all occurrences of an element from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using `java.util.ArrayList`, I want to remove all the occurrences of a particular element.

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("first");
    l.add("first");
    l.add("second");

    l.remove("first");
```

It's removing only the first occurrence. But I want all the occurrences to be removed after `l.remove("first");` I expect list to be left out only with the value "second". I found by googling that it can be achieved by creating new list and calling `list.removeAll(newList)`. But is it possible to remove all occurrences without creating new list or is there any API available to achieve it ?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
l.removeAll(Collections.singleton("first"));
```

Comment: or `l.removeAll(Collections.singletonList("first"));` to be more explicit.

Answer (score 40):

Another way using Java 8:

```
l.removeIf("first"::equals);
```

Comment: More compact but less readable than accepted answer

Answer (score 25):

```
while(l.remove("first")) { }
```

This removes all elements "first" from the list.

Comment: `List.remove()` returns boolean value.

Comment: @RohitJain it returns a boolean value and at the same time removes the value. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @KyelJmD.. Yeah that's true, but you can't compare the boolean return value with null. Just remove the later part in while loop.

Comment: I confused it with the remove(int index) overload. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Intellij Idea complains about empty code block. Furthermore is slower, and I feel also unreadable and cumbersome.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method.

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("someDuplicateString"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since in your example you are using Strings I guess did should do the trick.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
    if(list.get(i).equals(someStringNameOrValue)){
        list.remove(i--);
    }
}
```

Looks like I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. Am I right? you want to remove all occurrences of "first" ?

Comment: You will need to remove from the end to avoid skipping elements or you can `list.remove(i--);`