# How to remove two different Object having same class from List in java

Tags: java

What is best practice for removing two different Object having same class? List have `Class` file that create proxy by `Factory`.

```
List<? extends Class> listObject = new ArrayList();
...
Factory.createProxyObjectFromclassFile(List<? extends Class> list);
```

...
now I want to remove other `Object` from `listObject` like this:

```
removeMethod(Class<?> clazz){
listObject.remove(clazz.newInstance())
}
```

This is not possible because reference of `Objects` is not the same.

Comment: My guess is you want to remove a Class from a list of classes so just use `listObject.remove(clazz)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Equals method of every object you insert so that it checks the class of the objct instead of the ref id

For example, you could have a superclass ForList with the overridden equals() method and insert only objects extending thag class.

If you want to any possible type of class, you may want to extend the List class with your own implementation so it will check on classes instead of using the default equals()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly but if your list is composed of Class instances and you want to remove all instances of a certain class from the list, you should do something like:

```
private static void removeMethod(Class<?> clazz) {
    listObject.removeAll(Collections.singleton(clazz));
}
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565876/remove-all-occurrences-of-an-element-from-arraylist)